# How stream tweets if only are clients connected to the server

Tags: node.js, twitter, socket.io

I've developed a very simple node application where I'm using "Sokect.IO" to stream tweets using "ntwitter" from a particular twitter account.

So I've this code when there is a new tweet:

```
twit.stream('user', {track:'KITKAT'}, function(stream) {
    stream.on('data', function (data) {
        try{
            var tweet = {};
            tweet.name = data.user.name;
            tweet.avatar = data.user.profile_image_url;
            tweet.content = data.text;
            tweet.dateTime = moment(data.created_at).format('llll');
            //console.log(tweet);
            socketServer.sockets.emit("tweet", tweet);
        } catch(e){
            console.log("Error: " + e);
        }
    });
});

socketServer.sockets.on("connection", function(socket){
    console.log("new socket");
    var origen = socket.handshake.address.address;
    if(origen == "127.0.0.1")
        return;
    socket.emit("connection", "connection refuse: " + origen);
    socket.disconnect();

});
```

"The problem" is this will always try to stream a new tweet even when there are no users on the web site watching the tweets.

How can I limit this in order to get the tweets only when I've have users connected?

You can see an example of what I'm doing in: http://juanjardim.com/work/node

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to store your connections in and then iterate over an object ou array to emit the tweet, if there are no connections store your loops will do nothing check this question: [Nodejs, clients not always receiving server messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19662894/nodejs-clients-not-always-receiving-server-messages/19664632#19664632)